# regex to identify string and numbers from data

Tags: regex, pcre

**Jhon Wick is my name i spent 50$ everyday**

i need last name of the person with 50$ 
i made a regex to identify lastname of a person which is comming after first name every time .

this is the regex for it 
**^\w+\s+(\w+).+$**

but i need to retrieve 50$ also .

so, please help me to make this type of regex

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: i want **wick** and **50$** from this string

Comment: every string will be of same format from your sample?

Comment: yes in every string last name is at second word but number is at anywhere in string.
like 
**jay sharma is my name i spent 50$ in week**
i want **sharma** and **50$** out of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all dollar matches.

`^\w+\s+(\w+)|(\d+\$)` with the global tag.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uT1gQ7/1)

The idea is that you want two separate matches, as when you use line-related characters `^` or `$`, or even `*` and `+` in some cases, you are likely to get only first or final match.

After you get your name result, the regex just finds all dollar values without looking at their context whatsoever.

Comment: thanx for helping me 
@Andris Leduskrasts

Comment: The problem will be that if the string doesn't contain a name, it will still match if there are just values.

Comment: @Marcos You're right about getting dollar values without the presence of the name. However, the way OP wrote it, he doesn't actually check if it's a name, just the second word in the string. So just /g solves all the problems. If there was a specific requirement for the name (i.e. capital letters), then yes, your concerns would be valid.

Comment: in my task last name comes after first name every-time in capitalized format and den some number is den the string . so i think this regex which u help me with, its perfect for this.
@AndrisLeduskrasts

Comment: So there are no "tricky" strings. Then this will work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^\w+\s+(\w+).+?(\d+\$)
```

Comment: woohh ...
thank you @Marcos Dimitrio
thank you so much

Comment: It will match only one value though, if that's ok with you. (for example 50$ or 70$ it will match 50$)

Comment: yes You are right @Andris Leduskrasts but .
but if u have that type of match then please help me with it also ..

Comment: Wrote an answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for three or more word names also:

```
/\s+(\w+)\s+(?=is).*(?<=spent)\s+(\d+\$)/;
```